# The page in WinUI3 cannot be filled automatically in TabViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3

[OrderV.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIBQo.png)   [wrong effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtsCN.png)  [desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMcMd.png)

```cs
 Frame frame = new Frame();
 frame.Navigate(typeof(OrderV));

 TabViewItem tabViewItem = new()
 {
     Header = "Order",
     Content = frame
 };
 
tabViewItem.IsSelected = true;
TabViewControl.TabItems.Add(tabViewItem);
```

I've tried using Frame alone and it's fine, but I want Page to work in a TabViewItem

```xml
<Frame Name="MenuFrame" />
```

```cs
MenuFrame.Navigate(typeof(OrderV));
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what is not working? I pasted your code in a plain TabView sample project and it loads tabs contents without problem.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding  Sorry, I have uploaded the correct and wrong effects in the form of pictures. The problem is that the height of the second row of the Grid cannot fill the entire TabViewItem. I also upload the detailed code in the form of pictures. Thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` to your `TabView` control. Here is a minimal sample from your code.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Content="Start" />
    <TabView
        x:Name="TabViewControl"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame = new();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(OrderV));

        TabViewItem tabViewItem = new()
        {
            Header = "Order",
            Content = frame
        };

        tabViewItem.IsSelected = true;
        TabViewControl.TabItems.Add(tabViewItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that solved the problem, looks like I'm going to relearn the basics of xaml

Comment: Glad this helped. One tip though. Instead of pictures, it'd be easier to help if you post minimal reproducible code of your problem. People can copy and paste your code in sample projects and try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: ok this is my first day using stackoverflow, thanks a lot for your advice